# Ассемблер зациклился

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Есть задание "Образовать строку из исходной, повторив 1-й и элемент 1 раз, 2-й элемент   2 раз, 3 и элемент – 3 раза и тд." на с++ с ассемблерными вставками. написал программу:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void readName(char a)
{
    cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    char mass[7] = "stroka";
    char a='a';
    int len = 6;
    __asm
    {
        mov esi, -1
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, 0
        go:
            inc esi
            inc ecx
            jmp m1 
            cmp esi, len
        jne go

        m1 :
            mov al, mass[esi]
            push ax
            call readName
            inc ebx
            cmp ebx, ecx        
        jne m1

        mov ax, 1
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

код должен работать по аналогии с кодом на с++:

```
char str[] = "stroka";
int k=1;
string newStr;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    newStr += str[i];
  }
  k++;
}
```

но почему-то зацикливается на выведении первого символа. Помогите, пожалуйста)
P.S. все делал в vs 2019

Comment: Вам нужно сформировать строку или только вывести ее на экран?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , только вывести на экран

Comment: Так а что это вообще написано такое? В чем смысл команд `cmp esi, len` и `jne go`, если они не достижимы в принципе?

Comment: @AnT cmp esi, len - проверка на достижение конца массива. они не достигаются и в этом проблема(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала основы: пользовательский код может изменять регистры `eax`, `edx`, `ecx`, а все остальные регистры, если изменяются, должны восстановить свои прежние значения. Отсюда две ваших ошибки

1. Вы легко модифицируете регистры `esi`, `ebx`
2. Вы надеетесь, что функция `printName` не изменит ваши регистры

Если эти две ошибки исправить и немного подрихтовать код, то получится так

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void __cdecl printChar(char a)
{
    cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    char mass[7] = "stroka";
    __asm
    {
        pushad  // сохраняем все регистры в стек
        pushfd  // сохраняем регистр флагов в стек
        lea esi, mass  // загружаем в esi указатель на первый символ
        cld
        mov ebx, 1  // текущий индекс символа
        push eax  // зарезервировали место в стеке
        go:
            lodsb  // загружаем текущий символ в al
            test al, al  // если загрузили \0, 
            jz exit_  // то выходим
            mov edi, ebx  // в edi счетчик текущего символа
            mov [esp], eax  // а сам символ в стек
            loopChar:
                call printChar
                dec edi  // уменьшили счетчик
                jz endChar  // если счетчик = 0, то вышли из цикла
            jmp loopChar  // в цикле выводим символ
            endChar:
            inc ebx  // увеличили текущий индекс
        jmp go  // повторили операцию 
        exit_:
            pop eax  // не забыли достать символ из стека
            popfd     // восстановили регистр флагов
            popad   // восстановили регистры
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Помогло, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

В коде много бессмыслицы, но сразу можно заметить:

1. Вызов функции `readName` будет разрушать содержимое некоторых регистров. В частности `ecx`. Поэтому ваши надежды на то, что содержимое `ecx` сохранится, необоснованы.
2. В чем вообще заключется идея цикла

   ```
   m1 :
   ...
   cmp ebx, ecx        
   jne m1
   ```

   ?

   Вы сами внутри этого цикла ничего не меняете: ни `ebx`, ни `ecx`. Почему вы ожидаете, что этот цикл когда-то закончится?

Comment: да, забыл дописать inc ebx. поправил вопрос. ecx меняется перед входом в цикл. но даже с дописанным inc ebx все равно не выходит из цикла. в ассемблере не силен)

Comment: @he1pmep1ease: См. пункт 1.